# How to extract a subset from a formula in R

Tags: r, formula

Say I have a formula: `formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5` and I want to randomly select two of those predictors to make `Y ~ RandomPredictor1 + RandomPredictor2`. How would I do so in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reformulate` to create the formula. Put the predictors in a vector and select random two using `sample`

```
vars = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5")
#If you already have the formula, you can do 
#vars = all.vars(formula)[-1]

set.seed(40)
reformulate(termlabels = sample(vars, 2), response = "y")
#y ~ X4 + X5

set.seed(35)
reformulate(termlabels = sample(vars, 2), response = "y")
#y ~ X5 + X1
```

Answer (score 1):

A small addendum to the answer of d.b: if the names of predictors are not known, you can retrieve them from **formula** using

```
vars = attr(terms(formula), 'term.labels')
```